# Обновление TimeStamp после Commit транзакции

Tags: sql-server

Реально ли обновлять значение `TimeStamp` в строке после ком комита транзакции?

Сразу поясню зачем мне это надо. Для фиксирование "новых" данных у меня в программе отслеживается значение `TimeStamp` по каждой таблице, каждый интервал я фиксирую новые или измененные строки по `TimeStamp` значению. Все работает замечательно, однако есть нюанс.

- Создали снапшот транзакцию 1
- Создали снапшот транзакцию 2
- Добавили строку под транзакцией 1 (`TimeStamp` = 0x0000000000000011)
- Добавили строку под транзакцией 2 (`TimeStamp` = 0x0000000000000012)
- Коммит транзакции 2

На этом этапе, допустим программа отловила новую строку (`TimeStamp` = 0x0000000000000012) и занесла данные в свой КЭШ, после чего установила максимальный `TimeStamp` по изменениям 0x0000000000000012.

- Коммит транзакции 1

А вот тут программа **не отловит** новую строку, поскольку 0x0000000000000011<0x0000000000000012

Но если у меня удастся обновить `TimeStamp` после коммита, то все строчки отловятся как новые.

Comment: А _"программа отловила"_ - это еще в одной отдельной третьей snapshot транзакции?

Comment: Программа отлавливает "новые строки" выбирая по `WHERE [TimeStamp]>MaxTimeStamp`, где MaxTimeStamp это максимальный из всех предыдущих `TimeStamp`, селект в программе работает без явных транзакций

Comment: Можно попытаться быть может использовать как-то функцию `min_active_rowversion()`, не уверен (зависит от логики приложения). Альтернатива - использование _Change Tracking_ (пример, если нужно, составлю). При использовании Change Tracking версия данных не повышается, пока не произошёл `commit`. Т.е., в данном случае, транзакция 1, несмотря на то, что изменяла данные раньше транзакции 2, а её `commit` случился позднее, увеличила бы версию.

Comment: @i-one вчера изучал данную тему, скорее всего на Change Tracking и остановлюсь, оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним из возможных решений может быть проверка значения функции [min_active_rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb839514.aspx):

```
select ...
from [TableName]
where [TimeStamp] > @lastTimeStamp
    and @@dbts < min_active_rowversion();
```

В этом случае в ситуации, описанной в вопросе, после `commit` в транзакции 2 ничего возвращено бы не было (дополнительное условие будет иметь значение *false*, т.к. есть незавершенная rowversion-активная транзакция 1). Обе добавленные строки были бы возвращены после `commit` в транзакции 1. Т.е. при данной модификации "новые данные" могут запаздывать.

Жирным минусом `min_active_rowversion` является её неизбирательность. Данная функция не позволяет понять, работает ли незавершенная транзакция с интересующей нас таблицей, или с какой-то другой, в которой также есть поле типа `timestamp` (`rowversion`). Т.е. возможны ситуации, когда "новые данные" не будут отдаваться по ложному поводу.

Если приложение допускает возможные запаздывания данных (в т.ч. по ложным поводам), то дополнительная проверка может быть выходом.

---

Альтернативой может быть использование [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb933874.aspx) - встроенного функционала для отслеживания изменённых данных в таблицах.

При использовании *Change Tracking*, в отличие от `rowversion`, инкремент версии данных происходит не в момент исполнения команды, а при `commit` транзакции. Также сохраняется информация об удалённых строках данных, чего `rowversion` механизмы не обеспечивают.

Для использования данного функционала нужно включить соответствующую опцию на базе данных:

```
alter database [DbName] set change_tracking = on;
```

И на самой таблице:

```
alter table [TableName] enable change_tracking;
```

По-умолчанию данные об изменениях хранятся 2 дня и удаляются автоматически. Опциями базы данных в некоторых пределах можно изменить период хранения, а автоудаление может быть отключено.

Запрос для получения новых и изменённых данных будет выглядеть приблизительно следующим образом (проверку `change_tracking_min_valid_version` опустил для простоты):

```
-- это значение передаётся из приложения
declare @lastVersion bigint = ...
-- это значение будет использоваться как @lastVersion в следующий раз
select change_tracking_current_version();

select T.*
from [TableName] T
    join changetable(changes [TableName], @lastVersion) CT on CT.ID = T.ID;
```

Т.е. таблица соединяется по первичному ключу со специальной табличной функцией [changetable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb934145.aspx), которой передаётся номер версии, полученной в предыдущий раз.